# Boosting in solr search

Tags: asp.net-mvc, solr

I am using solr search in my MVC .NET application. Now I am doing a free search on it. How can I use boosting in my solr search?

Thanks.

Comment: You probably want to be a bit more specific about what you want to boost...

Comment: Impossible to answer this non-question.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you've looked at the [Boost Query and Function documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#bq_.28Boost_Query.29), as well as the [Solr Relevancy Cookbook section on Boosting Ranking Terms](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyCookbook#Boosting_Ranking_Terms)?